# Frequency Histogram in Clickhouse with unique and non unique data

Tags: clickhouse

I have a event table with created_at(DateTime), userid(String), eventid(String) column. Here userid can be repetitive while eventid is always unique uuid.

I am looking to build both unique and non unique frequency histogram.

This is for both eventid and userid on basis of given three input

1. start_datetime
2. end_datetime and
3. interval (1 min, 1 hr, 1 day, 7 day, 1 month).

Here, bucket will be decided by (end_datetime - start_datetime)/interval.

Output comes as start_datetime, end_datetime and frequency. 
For any interval, if data is not available then start_datetime and  end_datetime comes but with frequency as 0.

How can I build a generic query for this?

I looked in histogram function but could not find any documentation for this. While trying it, i could not understand relation behind the input and output.

Comment: look at some examples of using *histogram*: https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/tests/queries/0_stateless/00647_histogram.sql

Comment: @vladimir Thanks for link. I tried it but not sure how can we force intervals here to span in 1 min, 1hr, 1 day, 7 day etc here

Answer (score 1):

`count(distinct XXX)` is deprecated.

More useful `uniq(XXX)` or `uniqExact(XXX)`

Comment: Ok. But looks like it CH is translating count(distinct XXX) into uniqExact(XXX). Though performance is still low

Answer (score 0):

I got it work using following. Here, toStartOfMonth can be changed to other similar functions in CH.

```sql
select toStartOfMonth(`timestamp`) interval_data , count(distinct uid) count_data 
from g94157d29.event1 
where `timestamp` >= toDateTime('2018-11-01 00:00:00') and `timestamp` <= toDateTime('2018-12-31 00:00:00') 
GROUP BY interval_data;
```

and

```sql
select toStartOfMonth(`timestamp`) interval_data , count(*) count_data
from g94157d29.event1
where `timestamp` >= toDateTime('2018-11-01 00:00:00') and `timestamp` <= toDateTime('2018-12-31 00:00:00') 
GROUP BY interval_data;
```

But performance is very low for >2 billion records each month in event table where toYYYYMM(timestamp) is partition and toYYYYMMDD(timestamp) is order by.

Distinct count query takes > 30GB of space and 30 sec of time. Yet didn't complete.

While, General count query takes 10-20 sec to complete.